Segmentation Fault when llvm::MemoryBuffer::getFile on aarch64 with llvm16/17
I'm running code
#include <llvm/Bitcode/BitcodeReader.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/LLJIT.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/ThreadSafeModule.h>

llvm::Expected<llvm::orc::ThreadSafeModule> parseIRfile(llvm::StringRef filename){
    auto Ctx = std::make_unique<llvm::LLVMContext>();
    llvm::ErrorOr<std::unique_ptr<llvm::MemoryBuffer>> BufferOr = llvm::MemoryBuffer::getFile(filename);
    if (!BufferOr) {
        llvm::errs() << "Can not open: " << BufferOr.getError().message()
        << "\n";
        llvm::errs().flush();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    llvm::MemoryBuffer *Buffer = BufferOr.get().get();
    auto ME = llvm::parseBitcodeFile(Buffer->getMemBufferRef(), *Ctx);

    return llvm::orc::ThreadSafeModule(std::move(ME.get()), std::move(Ctx));
}

int main() {
    auto TSM = parseIRfile("xxx.bc");
    return 0;
}

Compile command is ↓
clang++-15 -g zllvm.cpp `llvm-config-15 --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core orcjit support nativecodegen` -O3 -o zllvm.o
On x86-64, The code works well on llvm15/16/17. When I run the code on aarch64, the code works well on llvm15, but get Segmentation fault on llvm16/17, output is like ↓
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000fffff1ed6934 in llvm::MemoryBuffer::getFile(llvm::Twine const&, bool, bool, bool, std::optional<llvm::Align>) () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-16.so.1
The aarch64 machine is ubuntu 18.04 with kunpeng920, not Mac with M1/2/3.
I have no idea why the error occurred. Could anyone give me some help?

Can you make a [mcve]?

Have you tried gdb/lldb or valgrind/sanitizers?

I have already reedit the code for an example@NateEldredge
